# How can I remove opacity of one element when user scrolls to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage like this http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/47/ and as you can see there's a transparent square in the 2nd section.
So far the video on the first page has the texture overlay:

```
.texture-overlay2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Is there a way of removing this dark overlay inside the little square on the second section?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tweak a little bit you javascript,

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var i = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(i>200){ // you decide here what to do once the scroll of the page is over 200px (or whatever value you need)
        // hide the background here
        $('.texture-overlay2').hide();
    }else{
        $('.texture-overlay2').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: is there a way of doing this transition more smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add this into your CSS:

```
#black{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

It's probably not what you wanted, but it might give you further ideas.